# Working of discount coupons on the checkout page in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon, totals, checkout-page

**I am trying to understand the working of discount coupon codes on the checkout page.**

When we apply any coupon code, then the discount is added to cart without reloading the page.

I have checked and found some below points:

- "**discount**" totals segment is added by **Magento_SalesRule** module.

When we apply any coupon code then, using `vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\view\frontend\web\js\action\set-coupon-code.js`, an ajax request is send to `rest/default/V1/carts/mine/coupons/:coupon`.

Code from `vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\view\frontend\web\js\action\set-coupon-code.js` :

```
 return storage.put(
            url,
            {},
            false
        ).done(function (response) {
            var deferred;

            if (response) {
                deferred = $.Deferred();

                isApplied(true);
                totals.isLoading(true);
                getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
                $.when(deferred).done(function () 
                {
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    totals.isLoading(false);
                });
                messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                    'message': message
                });
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            totals.isLoading(false);
            errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
        });
```

- After the above ajax call, Summary total section gets refresh and
  Discount appears in it below image.

[image: apply coupon]

- When we click on the cancel coupon button then code from
  `vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\view\frontend\web\js\action\cancel-coupon.js`
  runs and "Discount" disappears from the summary total section.

[image]

**How does the total_segments add or remove "discount"?**

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: Hi @SureshChikani, I wanted to add custom fee to total_segments like a discount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) For customer account:** `/V1/carts/mine/coupons/:couponCode`

I just explain how sale rules work for customer logged

**a) Set coupon:**

*vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml*

```
<route url="/V1/carts/mine/coupons/:couponCode" method="PUT">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="set"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Cart::manage" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

So, the service class interface class `Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface::set()` will be used and `Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement::set` will be called.

```
$quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
$this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
```

When quote collects totals: `$quote->collectTotals()`

`\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount::collect()` will be called. It will calculate the coupon logic here.

**b) Remove coupon:**

*vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml*

```
<route url="/V1/carts/mine/coupons" method="DELETE">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="remove"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

`Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement::remove()` will be called.

c) **Total Segment:** `V1/carts/mine/payment-information`

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/webapi.xml*

```
<route url="/V1/carts/mine/payment-information" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface" method="getPaymentInformation"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php*

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getPaymentInformation($cartId)
{
    ...
    $paymentDetails->setTotals($this->cartTotalsRepository->get($cartId));
    ...
}
```

**\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository::get()**

```
 if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
        $addressTotalsData = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
        $addressTotals = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getTotals();
    } else {
        $addressTotalsData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        $addressTotals = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getTotals();
    }
......

$calculatedTotals = $this->totalsConverter->process($addressTotals);
$quoteTotals->setTotalSegments($calculatedTotals);
```

This will get the totals data and set the total segments.

`\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsReader::fetch()`

```
foreach ($this->collectorList->getCollectors($quote->getStoreId()) as $reader) {
        $data = $reader->fetch($quote, $total);
```

**2) For guest account**, we can see the apis:

*vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml*

```
<!-- Managing Guest Cart Coupons -->
<route url="/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/coupons" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCouponManagementInterface" method="get"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
<route url="/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/coupons/:couponCode" method="PUT">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCouponManagementInterface" method="set"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
<route url="/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/coupons" method="DELETE">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCouponManagementInterface" method="remove"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wanted to add a custom fee to total_segments like discount,  
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsReader::fetch() this line helped me.

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh, can you please help here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296379/how-to-show-applied-discount-from-shopping-cart-on-shipping-step-checkout-page-m

Comment: How is error message shown when the coupon code is invalid?