# How to show Applied discount from Shopping Cart on Shipping Step Checkout Page Magento 2?

Tags: shipping, magento2.3.1, discount, coupon, checkout-page

Please Check Attached screenshot:[image]

On **Checkout Page** under **Shipping Step** i want to display Shopping Cart page applied discount **Coupon Code and Amount**.

Please check below code:

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"
                                                                  xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                                                        </item>

                                                </item>

                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                   </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If Anyone having any idea please suggest, Thanks in Advance!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code worked for me.

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"
                                                                  xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                                                        </item>

                                                </item>

                                            </item>

                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
                                                            </item>
                                            </item>

                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                   </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: here i got perfect solutions on it https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/display-order-summary-in-shipping-step-checkout-magento-2/ it will display all data as like: totals, shipping amount, discount, tax and etc.